# C++ {fmt} fmt::vformat with wide-string and fmt::make_wformat_args fails to compile

Tags: c++, wstring, fmt

This code fails to compile. (`error: no matching function for call to 'vformat(std::wstring&, fmt::v10::format_arg_store<fmt::v10::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v10::detail::buffer<wchar_t> >, wchar_t>, int>)')`

```cpp
#include <fmt/xchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arg_1 = 12;
    std::wstring format = L"Hello {}";
    std::wstring test = fmt::vformat(format, fmt::make_wformat_args(arg_1));
    std::wcout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

However, this code successfully compiles.

```cpp
#include <fmt/xchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arg_1 = 12;
    std::string format = "Hello {}";
    std::string test = fmt::vformat(format, fmt::make_format_args(arg_1));
    std::cout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using {fmt} 10.0.0 and including xchar.h, `fmt::format` works as I would expect with wide strings, it seems I am facing this problem with only `fmt::vformat`.

I have tried including various separate fmt header files in different configurations (fmt/core.h, fmt/format.h, fmt/xchar.h). This seems pointless as xchar.h includes the other libraries header files.

While I specifically use MSVC, I have tried and have had the same issue on GCC.

I have tried using `fmt::make_format_args` instead.

I have also tried specifying the `fmt::wformat_context` template parameter for `fmt::make_wformat_args`.

My specific use case has me using localization files from disk, so I cannot know the format strings at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `fmt::vformat` except when writing a formatting function yourself. A proper way to pass a format string only known at runtime is by wrapping it in `fmt::runtime` and calling `fmt::format`:

```cpp
#include <fmt/xchar.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int arg_1 = 12;
  std::wstring format = L"Hello {}";
  std::wstring test = fmt::format(fmt::runtime(format), arg_1);
  std::wcout << test;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4WKd575o7

Answer (score 1):

`vformat`'s first argument is a string view. Seems like `<fmt/xchar.h>` adds an overload like:

```cpp
template<typename Char>
std::basic_string<Char> fmt::vformat(fmt::basic_string_view<Char>, basic_format_args<some_non_deduced_context>);
```

So `Char` can't be deduced from `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`, and you need an actual `fmt::basic_string_view`:

```cpp
std::wstring test = fmt::vformat(fmt::wstring_view(format), fmt::make_wformat_args(arg_1));
```